# Need advice on Encrypting whole Hard Disk

Tags: windows-7, security

I need to send private data overseas on a hard disk.

It is 500 GB HDD with Win-7 Ultimate 64 bit.

It has 5 Partitions including system partition.

What is the best & Easiest way of Encrypting the entire hard disk ?

I don't mind spending to Buy any kind of software.

I did look at " Folder Lock " software which allows you to make individual lockers which are encrypted but I don't know how good that encryption is & whether the system partition can encrypted. It doesn't say what algorithm is used. Plus point is that it is fairly easy to use.

Does the type of algorithm make any difference ?

Thanks

Comment: When it's so important data woulnd it be safer to send the data online?

Comment: @Robert How would it be safer?

Comment: Send the data encrypted over a VPN and your safe. Sending it with traditional transport might get the disk lost or damaged ...

Comment: @Robert Ah, you were thinking of safety in terms of loss of data rather than interception. Well, I'd agree with you on this (although I really hope that Dan has a backup of his data), but depending on your internet connections, sending 500GB via VPN may not be an option.

Comment: Many Thanks to you all. I also don't mind spending to get the job done, but being not so a Geek, I need simple solution with total security. I do have back ups so if something goes wrong, I can do it all over again. So what is the simplest way ? Thank You all.

Answer (score 7):

I use [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) in production, 1 year so far no problems.

**Update**

The stronger the algorithm typically the better the encryption, truecrypt gives you options and usually list them as less secure all the way to paranoid(!).

Comment: @DanD. done, side effect of double checking the url on google and then 'copying' the link from the page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Windows 7 Ultimate you can use the built-in [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/products/features/bitlocker) Drive Encryption to help protect all files stored on the drive Windows is installed on (operating system drive) and on fixed data drives (such as internal hard drives). Your can use BitLocker To Go to help protect all files stored on removable data drives (such as external hard drives or USB flash drives).

Comment: I don't have the bandwidth to transport it over the net.